# ConversionFailedException while using @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date]

Tags: java

ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '2021-02-28 11:25:13.665  0545'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "**2021-02-28 11:25:13.665  0545**" is malformed at " 0545"

What would be the pattern for above?
I have used "**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z**" pattern which results in above issue.

Comment: is "0545" an offset zone? do you want to convert to OffsetDateTime? or ZoneDateTime?

Comment: I want to convert to OffsetDateTime.

Comment: so you need that offset, right? is it possible to change the string request to '2021-02-28 11:25:13.665 +0545'? DateTimeFormatter needs + or - signs to decide the offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS HHmm**" to resolve the issue.